# Mixing RAND() and UNION gives random rowcount?

Tags: mysql, random, union

I was testing out a query to get a random integer in MySQL, and I noticed this behavior:

```
mysql> SELECT FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 5)) UNION SELECT FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 5)) UNION SELECT FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 5));
+-------------------------+
| FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 5)) |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |
|                       2 |
|                       4 |
+-------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 5)) UNION SELECT FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 5)) UNION SELECT FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 5));
+-------------------------+
| FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 5)) |
+-------------------------+
|                       4 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 5)) UNION SELECT FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 5)) UNION SELECT FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 5));
+-------------------------+
| FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 5)) |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |
|                       4 |
|                       0 |
+-------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I seem to be getting a random number of rows in the result set! There are 3 `UNION`ed `SELECT`s in there. What is going on? I was thinking that maybe one of the results from the rand statement was no tuple because of the `RAND()`, but that doesn't make sense -- there should be *some* result, a `NULL` at least!

```
mysql> select version();
+-------------------+
| version()         |
+-------------------+
| 5.0.51a-24+lenny4 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNION` eliminates duplicate results because it's a set-wise operator.  If you want duplicates retained, use `UNION ALL`.  Maybe I've misunderstood your question, but this seems like exactly the type of results I'd expect for this query.

Comment: @user57567567567: using `UNION ALL`, like I said

Comment: A set-wise operator means it affects the entire result set?

Comment: set-wise means it operates on sets.  And sets can not have duplicate elements in them.

Comment: So using a set-wise operator in a MySQL result forces it into a being a set?